# SendGrid client lifetime and thread-safety

Tags: c#, .net, sendgrid

From [GitHub](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/d262b7f5d38250d774b4ca6494e2f7e6244669c8/src/SendGrid.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L23) I see that normal way to register the SendGrid client is using transient lifetime. I am not able to find info about thread safety for SendGrid client. Is it possible to use it in multiple threads? Any pros/cons to register it as a transient dependency, not as a singleton?

Comment: If authors of the library do not tell very clear in documenation that their library is thread safe then you should assume it's not an act accordingly.

Comment: The Dependency Injection extensions provided by SendGrid register an HTTP client factory which injects the HTTP client into their SendGrid client. The HTTP client factory manages the lifetime of the HTTP client, the factory and HTTP client itself is thread safe.
However, I do not know if the SendGrid client code is thread safe, I will try to research this and get back to you.

Comment: If you don't want the service added as a transient, I'd suggest to inspire on the source code you linked and register it as a scoped or singleton. I don't think it would cause any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SendGrid client is registered as a transient service when calling the `AddSendGrid` method. If you'd like to register the service as scoped or singleton you can, but there's no built-in helper. You can copy the source code for `AddSendGrid` and adjust as needed.

The SendGrid client and its dependencies (HTTP client) do not have code that could cause race conditions or deadlocks as far as I can tell, so it should be thread safe.